# What material performs best in this situation?

Tags: structural-engineering, materials, structural-analysis, statics, material-science

Take a long, thin rod, say .25 mm in diameter and 200 mm in length.

Filling these fixed dimensions, what kinds of materials could the rod be made of such that it minimizes how much the rod bends under its own weight, assuming it's held horizontally at one end?

What quantitative property would describe a given material's performance in the above case?

Comment: Sounds like you basically want the stiffness per unit mass, which is usually referred to as the specific modulus. As far as the material goes, the highest of which I'm aware in this respect are high alumina ceramics.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Carbon fiber is probably easier and cheaper to get though. Is alumina even stiffer higher than carbon fiber for its weight?

Comment: Check material tables - select one that suits.

Comment: @DKNguyen: yes, carbon fiber is probably easier to get. Yes, I believe some of the ceramics are stiffer per unit mass.

Comment: Until you hear a quite "tink" followed by swearing -- then you know you needed to think about toughness, too.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, isn’t carbon fibre only stiff along the direction of the fiber? Isn’t it flexible like string?

Comment: @JoeyPeluka: Yes, the individual fibers tend to be fairly flexible, so you normally start by weaving them into cloth, then using epoxy (or similar) to bind them together so you can get a panel, rod, etc., that acts pretty much like a homogeneous unit. You can get cloth woven with various ratios of the directions to get strength in the directions you need for the part you're designing.

Comment: @TimWescott: Depends, of course. There are certainly plenty of cases where toughness matters. But there are a few cases (e.g., precision measurement equipment) where stability and rigidity matter a lot, but stress is expected to be extremely minimal.

Comment: Carbon fiber is only stiff along the direction of the fiber, but when you extrude a bunch of them into a rod the result is pretty stiff, even if they're unidirectional.  The _best_ stiffness would be some sort of a woven or other two-angle layup, but there's not much room to do that in 1/4 of a mm.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Oh, absolutely.  I just have a certain knee-jerk reaction when I see engineers optimizing along just one axis.  Which in some cases emerges as humorously pointing out how the product will fail in the field, while maintaining optimality on that one axis.  I would assume that if you did have some piece of kit with a long stiff ceramic rod then it would break all the time (or require extreme care).  This would lead to technicians the world over cursing your design decision, while at the same time acknowledging that it needed to be made.

Comment: @TimWescott: Yup. In fact, I'd go so far as to guess that many of the most serious failures come from optimizing too much along one axis, while (more or less) ignoring other things that turn out to be more important than somebody thought/believed/recognized.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Sounds to me like you can put different ratios in different directions and put them in a resin to get stiffness in those directions as far as *tensile* stiffness, but I don’t think you could align them in any direction that would give the *bending* stiffness I was looking for in the example. Am I wrong in that supposition? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: The question only asks how to maximize stiffness, not for any particular level of stiffness, so I can't guess whether the goal you have in mind is achievable or not. As far as the cross-threads go: you want to bind the threads together so the whole rod acts as a unit--but the matrix (epoxy) isn't nearly as strong as carbon fiber, so the cross-threads are there mostly to help assure the lengthwise threads stay bound together to act as a unit. But you would want a high ratio of the threads to be along the length of the rod.

Comment: You need to add more constraints. The void, which contains exactly zero mass and thus cannot bend under its own weight will beat all materials. Surely you need this rod to do something? Bear some load that a non-existant material of non-existence can't do? Once you establish that, then combine materials with void to carve out a geometry within your cylinder constraints where you reduce mass to have less weight.

Comment: @Abel Would the void not also have a modulus of 0? Then we’re in a 0/0 situation. But I still see your point. How about this constraint: A material that does what I said before, but also has enough stiffness to not completely snap or deform from a very tiny force other than gravity

Comment: Quantify and remember why I-beams win over rectangular prisms of steel in this area. Supported frim one side (cantilever) or both sides? As long as you say "Within" rather than filling these dimensions with a geometry whose mass gradient is less than ___, a geometry problem exists in addition to material selection. With gradient, you end up at material density control (where something like styrofoam is great as opposed to say balsa wood)

Comment: @Abel 1 I’m not sure what you mean by mass gradient.

2 Like I said, the rod is held at one end, so it’s a cantilever. 

3 By “within” I meant taking the form of exactly, ie filling like you said. But, that’s interesting because I hadn’t considered that a rod whose cross section doesn’t take up the full possible cross section (a circle of diameter .25mm) could be more optimal than one that takes up the whole cross section. 

If it doesn’t have to take up the whole space, then letting the rod’s length approach zero is optimal. Let’s say it has to stretch the full length though.

Comment: @Abel If the rod’s cross section doesn’t have to fill the whole possible cross section, then the most optimal geometry to minimize deflection by balancing weight and stiffness would be a hollow cylinder, where the outer diameter is the .25mm and the inner diameter approaches arbitrarily close to .25mm.

But still: my original question asked for a fixed geometry, geometry wasn’t a part of the question. But even if it had been, it doesn’t matter because if material A performs better than material B in one geometry, it performs better than material B in *all* geometries.

Comment: Gravity is directionally biased. Cross section of your hollow cylinder is not. Not all materials are the same in all directions and as such not all materials perform the same in all geometries. If your goal is what I think it is from your comments and you care about manufacturability, i suggest you look at styrofoam aka polystyrene.