# What grade of steel best suits this application?

Tags: materials, statics, steel, metallurgy, metals

Take a long, thin, straight wire with a circular cross section. Say, .5mm in diameter and 200mm in length. Hold the wire horizontally at one end (cantilever). What grade of steel would result in the wire deflecting the least under its own weight? Would they all perform very closely to each other, or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What material performs best in this situation?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54912/what-material-performs-best-in-this-situation)

Comment: @Solar Mike No because this talks about steel specifically whereas that question talks about any material

Comment: All the comments apply, and all you need to do is compare material specs.

Comment: Steels are fairly similar to each other in terms of density and your question is concerned with modulus vs density. The heat treatment probably matters a lot more. That probably means properly heat treated high carbon steel will get you most of the way there. Carbons steel is quite difficult to beat versus other steels in terms of mechanical properties. It only really loses out when temperature or chemicals are concerned. Cheaper too. I wouldn't be surprised if someone told me modulus of steel is fairly similar across all steels and it's more the yield strength that differs from heat treatment

Comment: And according to this the heat treatment doesn't really affect the modulus of steel: https://knifesteelnerds.com/2018/03/13/why-doesnt-heat-treating-affect-steel-flex/